# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'prototype' of undefined (inherits_browser.js)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack

After porting our app to newer version of `create-react-app` following error started occurring:

[image]

Seems to be reffering to `inherits_browser.js` that is probably coming from some npm module that we can't pinpoint. Line error refers to in that file is `ctor.prototype = Object.create(superCtor.prototype,` and it seems like this is used by webpack somehow.

Has anyone experienced this issue before / can suggest what problematic areas this can occur in?

**EDIT**

Digging deeper issue seems to be coming from this file (cipherBase.js)

[image]

Comment: I am having this exact same problem today.... removing my node modules and reinstalling did not resolve the problem - curious did you resolve / how did you resolve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had this exact problem today. I guess I had some outdated package in my project's `node_modules` folder, because removing it and reinstalling everything fixed the problem.

```
rm -rf node_modules dist
npm install
webpack --config ./webpack_prod.config.js
```

Notice that in my case Webpack is installed locally as a **devDependency**. Doing `rm -rf node_modules` and `npm install` reinstalled Webpack and all dependencies.

For reference, I'm currently running Webpack 2.2.1, Node.js 7.7.4 and npm 4.1.2.