# Error in the angular project after installing woocommerce-api

Tags: angular, webpack, woocommerce-rest-api

I am facing some serious issues running my angular project after installing the 'woocommerce-api' package. The sequence of problems and the solutions I tried are:

**Problem 1 (fixed):** Can't resolve errors (crypto, fs, http, https, net, path, stream, tls, zlib) while building the project.

To solve this, I referred [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51087330/angular-6-many-cant-resolve-errors-crypto-fs-http-https-net-path-stream) which resolved the errors and project was getting compiled successfully.

**Problem 2 (fixed):** Uncaught ReferenceError: global is not defined.

This was also fixed referring [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50356408/upgrading-to-angular-6-x-gives-uncaught-referenceerror-global-is-not-defined) link.

**Ptoblem 3**: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'prototype' of undefined (inherits_browser.js)

Thought I had referred [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43276643/uncaught-typeerror-cannot-read-property-prototype-of-undefined-inherits-brow) link but the solution doesn't seem to help me out. Also, I got to know what in the below code was causing all the problems:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import * as WC from 'woocommerce-api';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})


 export class AppComponent {
      title = 'tempPro1';
      woo: any;
      constructor() {
        //Below line 
        this.woo = WC({
          url: "***",
          consumerSecret: "***",
          consumerKey: "***"
    });
   }
 }
```

The initialization in the constructor to `this.woo` is causing the error. If that line is removed, the error for the undefined prototype goes off. I understand Woocommmerce-api would be having some dependency which I am not able to figure out. Any inputs?

Here is the actual error screenshot:
[image: Error]

Comment: can you click on the inherits.browser.js to see where is the error come from